# Is th­is go­od cod­e? W­ill th­is w­or­k? For making a cross platform game?

Tags: c

```
static const volatile char slash =
#ifdef _WIN32
    '\\';
#   include <windows.h>
#   define mkdir(...) _mkdir(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
    '/';
#   include <sys/stat.h>
#   include <unistd.h>
#endif
```

­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: You may want `#if defined (_WIN32) || defined (_WIN64)` to catch both architectures.

Comment: `windows.h` provides a window and graphics API which you can program a GUI application, for which you would need an equivalent in Linux if you were trying to make a cross-platform non-console game.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Actually no. 64 bit windows still defines _WIN32.

Comment: @Joshua - I'm not sure that is true for all windows (including server, etc..) I'll have to dig up the MS docs for each. But they define `_WIN32`, `_WIN64` and `__WINNT` (each of the `32` and `64` bit macros also have variants of no-underscore and double-underscore).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nesting a preprocessor conditional inside a declaration will *work*, but it is generally considered bad style.  Avoid if possible; if you can't avoid it, don't put *anything else* inside the ifdef:

```
static const double MAGIC = 
  #ifdef ALGEBRA
    2.7182818284590452354
  #else
    3.1415926535897932384
  #endif
;
```

Windows accepts both `\` and `/` as directory separators, so in this case it would be better to use `/` unconditionally:

```
static const char slash = '/';
```

This constant does not need to be `volatile`. I don't think I've *ever* seen a situation where a variable was appropriately declared `const volatile`.

An `#ifdef _WIN32` to pick which headers to include and to paper over the `mkdir` / `_mkdir` variation is unobjectionable and in fact common.  However, it is *also* considered bad style to put an `#include` below the first top-level declaration in the file (except in connection with [X-macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro)).

Comment: `const volatile` --> code cannot write it, but it might change for other reasons.  (e.g. reading a memory mapped clock)

Answer (score 3):

Starting an expression outside the `#ifdef`, then completing it, twice, in two different ways, within a `#ifdef` / `#else` can be hard to read in the future.

Its frankly more straightforward to just repeat yourself, in violation of the DRY principle:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    static const volatile char slash ='\\';
#   include <windows.h>
#   define mkdir(...) _mkdir(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
    static const volatile char slash ='/';
#   include <sys/stat.h>
#   include <unistd.h>
#endif
```

Comment: It doesn't compile. You can't mix const and volatile. :(

Comment: @Joshua:  There is nothing wrong with `const volatile`, and it is often used in embedded system development.  If you are getting a compile-error, post the details.

Comment: @abelenky: Ok looks like that got fixed sometime down the line since I last tried it.